Why am I not getting credit for consecutive days on the site?
This may seem like a SE question, but it is only happening on this site. I have been onto the site every day for the last 56 days, but an only getting credited for 6 consecutive days. This has also happened before, where I lost my consecutive days. Every day I go onto the site, check the main page, check my profile, respond to anything ( usually nothing ). Just as I do with the other sites I am registered with.
And yes, I am just after the glittering, shiny gold 100 days badge......

According to the calendar, you missed the 17th.

Remember that since Stack Exchange uses UTC, a "day" may not start and end when you expected it to. You may have visited on the 17th in your timezone, but really it counted towards the 18th or the 16th in UTC land...
Also note that visits to the front page don't count.
I can relate to how you feel. I was sick two days this month, and if it weren't for that, I would have been the first to get the Fanatic badge.

The thing that puzzles me is that all the other sites seem to have me recorded on that day. It is probably as you say, that the UTC day was different, but it is annoying. Ah well, only 94 days to go....

@SchroedingersCat Worse yet, if you arrive just before midnight UTC and continue browsing after midnight, that doesn't count. Only the arrival time of each visit counts. I don't know when a visit is considered to be over, but it takes at least a few minutes. I consider this to be a stackexchange bug. Always check your personal User page to see which visit time the site has recorded. You may have to come back in an hour or so to get that timestamp to reset.
